# Common Mod Rewrite rule for two different pages?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one question can i use a common mod rewrite rule for two or more different pages? As for example i have two pages and below rewrite rule should work.

```
RewriteRule /(.*)\.html aboutus.php?pg=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule /(.*)\.html profile.php?pg=$1 [QSA]
```

But can i use some common rule so i don't have to repeat above for every page?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you add a `RewriteCond` only the first rule will have any effect because the first regex captures anything that ends with .html and then modifies it such that rule #2 will not match.

**Request Example**: http://domain.com/something/something/something.html?k=v

1. `/something/something/something.html` *matches* `/(.*)\.html`
2. *rewrites to* `aboutus.php?pg=something/something/something&k=v`
3. **No `L` flag** - continue to next RewriteRule
4. `aboutus.php?pg=something/something/something&k=v` *does not match* `/(.*)\.html`
5. **serve** `aboutus.php?pg=something/something/something&k=v`